# How to pass single tag header in php soap client for wcf?

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I am trying to consume WCF service from PHP . I need to pass a header field in soap client of PHP in order to consume it. Soap header will be something like this:

```
<header>
<LisenseKey>Lisense key goes here</LisenseKey>
</header>
```

The namespace for LisenseKey element is "http://mylinsensekeynamespace".

The method I want to consume in WCF is as follows:

```
public string function GetMessage(string name)
{
    return "Hello , "+name;
}
```

Before the service is configured to validate header, I was consuming the service from PHP as follows and it is working perfectly:

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8181/?wsdl");
    $param = new stdClass();
    $param->name = "My Name";
    $webService = $client->GetMessage($param);
    print_r($webService);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

When after the service is configured to validate license key in header, I am trying to consume it like this and it is not working yet:

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8181/?wsdl");

    $actionHeader = new SoapHeader("http://mycustomheader",'LisenseKey',"lisense key",true);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);
    $param = new stdClass();
    $param->name = "My Name";
    $webService = $client->GetMessage($param);
    print_r($webService);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

I already tried in so many different ways from online articles. How can I consume it? WCF service is using BasicHttpBinding and SOAP version should be 1.1. How to pass the header information to consume the service?

Following is the .NET WCF service code that validate for LicenseKey soap header for every request.

```
    public class MyServiceMessageInspector : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel,
            System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            if (request.Headers.FindHeader("LisenseKey", "") == -1)
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisense Key Was Not Provided");
            }

            var lisenseKey = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("LisenseKey", "http://mycustomheader.com");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lisenseKey))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisnse key should not be empty");
            }

            if (lisenseKey != "12345x")
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisense key is not valid");
            }

            return instanceContext;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyServiceMessageInspectorBehaviour : Attribute, System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (var endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyServiceMessageInspector());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the WCF service like this : `$client->__soapCall("GetMessage", $param, NULL, $header);`

Comment: What will be the structure of $header variable please ?

Comment: If the header is not mandatory then try setting `mustUnderstand` argument as `false` : `new SoapHeader("http://mycustomheader",'LisenseKey',"<license-key>",false);`. Also make sure you are passing the correct license key.